# ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, segmentation-fault, exc-bad-access, abaddressbook

I have this code:

```
void MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback(ABAddressBookRef addressBook, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context) {
    [(id)context reloadSpecifiers];
}

@interface JBPPreferencesListController : PSListController {
   ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
}
@end

@implementation JBPPreferencesListController
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
       // ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback, self);
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)specifiers {
    if (_specifiers == nil) {
        NSMutableArray *specs = [NSMutableArray array];
        [specs addObjectsFromArray:[self specifiersForContactGroups]];
        _specifiers = [specs copy];
    }
    return _specifiers;
}

-(NSArray *)specifiersForContactGroups {
    if (addressBook == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }
    CFIndex groupCount = ABAddressBookGetGroupCount(addressBook);
    if (groupCount == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    CFArrayRef allGroups = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBook);
    if (allGroups == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }
    PSSpecifier* allContactsSpec = [PSSpecifier preferenceSpecifierListItemNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Favourites %i", groupCount] value:@(-2)];
    NSMutableArray *groupSpecs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:allContactsSpec];
    for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
        ABRecordRef currentGroup = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allGroups, i);
        if (currentGroup != NULL) {
            NSString *groupName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(currentGroup, kABGroupNameProperty);
            NSNumber *groupID = @(ABRecordGetRecordID(currentGroup));
            PSSpecifier* specifier = [PSSpecifier preferenceSpecifierListItemNamed:groupName value:groupID];
            [groupName release];
            [groupSpecs addObject:specifier];
        }
    }
    CFRelease(allGroups);
    return [[groupSpecs copy] autorelease];
}
-(void)dealloc {
    if (addressBook != NULL) CFRelease(addressBook);
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

If I uncomment `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback` line in `init`, then it crashes (before the controller's view comes on screen) with EXC_BAD_ACCESS and segmentation fault, 11.

I am not using ARC, and I have groups on my phone (they appear when the line is commented out)

Comment: I assume you are sure that addressBook is not nil when you call ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback, are you?

Comment: well the rest of the code works when it's commented out, so I don't see why it suddenly become NULL and correlate perfectly to when I uncomment it?

Comment: You are right, if even addressBook were NULL, this would not cause the error. One more idea: You probably want to be your callback function local to your file. In this case, it should have the type static void. You declared it as void only which makes it global. I don't know if this has anything to do with your error, but you could try.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner, THANK YOU SO SO MUCH... I don't know why, but it fixed the problem after 2 long days. Thanks :)

Comment: my pleasure! I have learned something by myself.